# Counting; How many lists can I make from my list in the way described in the body below?

Tags: combinatorics

I think I have generated the right conjecture based on a pattern that I think I found. Can someone verify it for me? Also, I don't know how to properly asked the question so can you follow the pattern and see if you come to the same conclusion as myself.
You cannot change the order of the letters.
You can only change how it is grouped in the lists.

list1: $[a,b]$ -> So I can write new lists as $[ab]$ or $[a,b]$. That's two possibilities

list2: $[a,b,c]$ ->So I can write new lists as $[abc]$ or $[a,b,c]$ or $[ab,c]$ or $[a,bc]$. That's four possibilities.

list3: $[a,b,c,d]$ ->So I can write new lists as $[abcd]$ or $[a,b,c,d]$ or $[ab,c,d]$, $[a,bc,d]$ or $[a,b,cd]$ or $[abc,d]$ or $[a,bcd]$ or $[ab,cd]$. That's eight.

So for a list of $n$ elements...I can write my new lists in the way I did above and there would be $2^{n-1}$ lists.

I will do my best to add more details if you don't think I have given enough to ask the question.
Thank you.

Comment: I think, but I'm not sure, that you are asking "given that we can either delete each of the commas (independently of each other) or leave it in place in the list $a,b,c,\cdots, n$ how many possible patterns can we get?"  But in that case you have $n-1$ commas, hence $n-1$ binary choices, so indeed there are $2^{n-1}$ possible patterns.

Comment: @lulu Thank you lulu. I don't know why I didn't think that way. Yep... so between each letter there is either no comma or a comma. You are right. Thank you. You have just made my problems so much simpler. Seriously!!! Thank you!